# Automapper, map by naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm using automapper to map my entities. But entities have different structure.

Source:

```
public class SourceEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Communication SelectedCommunication { get; set; }
}

public enum Type
{
    Type1=1,
    Typ2
}

[Flags]
public enum Communication
{
    Phone =1,
    Email =2,
    Post =4
}
```

Also I have `HasFlag()` extension method that will return true if flag is selected.

Destination entity:

```
public class DestinationEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Type1_PhoneSelected { get; set; }
    public bool Type1_EmailSelected { get; set; }
    public bool Type1_PostSelected { get; set; }
    public bool Type2_PhoneSelected { get; set; }
    public bool Type2_EmailSelected { get; set; }
    public bool Type2_PostSelected { get; set; }
}
```

My map:

```
        CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>()
            .ForMember(v => v.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(i => i.Name));
```

But I can't figure out the best way to map Types properties.
Is it possible to map it without typing something like:

```
.ForMemeber(v=>v.Test1_PhoneSelected, opt=>opt.MapFrom(i=>i.SelectedCommunication.HasFlag(Communication.Phone)))
.ForMemeber(v=>v.Test2_PhoneSelected, opt=>opt.MapFrom(i=>i.SelectedCommunication.HasFlag(Communication.Phone)))
```

For each of this properties.
Is there any way to map by naming convention?
Or any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom value resolvers](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)

> Although AutoMapper covers quite a few destination member mapping
>   scenarios,  there are the 1 to 5% of destination values that need a
>   little help in resolving.  Many times, this custom value resolution
>   logic is domain logic that can go straight on our domain.  However, if
>   this logic pertains only to the mapping operation, it would clutter
>   our source types with unnecessary behavior.  In these cases,
>   AutoMapper allows for configuring custom value resolvers for
>   destination members.

Example of custom value resolver:

```
public class YourCustomResolver
    : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, Communication, bool>
{
    private Communication _communication;

    public YourCustomResolver(
        Communication communication)
    {
    }

    public bool Resolve(
        object source, 
        object destination,
        Communication sourceMember, 
        bool destMember, 
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _communication == sourceMember;
    }
}
```

Your mapping will look like this:

```
CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestinationEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type1_PhoneSelected, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Phone), src => src.SelectedCommunication))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type1_EmailSelected, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Email), src => src.SelectedCommunication))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type1_PostSelected , opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Post) , src => src.SelectedCommunication))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type2_PhoneSelected, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Phone), src => src.SelectedCommunication))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type2_EmailSelected, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Email), src => src.SelectedCommunication))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Type2_PostSelected , opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new YourCustomResolver(Communication.Post) , src => src.SelectedCommunication));
```

Comment: Maybe you could go even further with ForAllMembers.